# How to decorate a recursive function in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, decorator

I have tried to decorate a non-recursive function. But I cannot find a way to do the same for a recursive function. Is it possible in C++ as of now?

I started with a simple recursive function.

```cpp
uint64_t fib(uint64_t n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
        return n;
    return fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1);
}
```

I thought of writing a decorator class to add memoization to this function.

```cpp
template <typename>
class memoized;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
class memoized<R(Args...)>
{
    using Callable = R (&)(Args...);

    size_t max_size;
    map<tuple<Args...>, R> cache;

    Callable target;

public:
    memoized(Callable func, size_t maxSize = 0)
        : target(func), max_size(maxSize)
    {
    }

    R operator()(Args... args)
    {
        auto t = make_tuple(args...);
        auto iter = cache.find(t);
        if (iter == cache.end())
        {
            iter = cache.insert(make_pair(t, target(args...))).first;
        }
        return iter->second;
    }
};
```

But this doesn't work. The recursion always happens. Maybe this is not the right to way to add decorator to a recursive function.

Comment: What do you mean by “decorate”? The term doesn’t have a generally recognised meaning in this context in C++. Furthermore, please show us what you’ve tried.

Comment: Means - apply a decorator pattern

Comment: @debashish.ghosh do you mean function decorators as in python ?

Comment: Templates maybe? Looks like decorators

Comment: If you are looking for design patter, just Google. Otherwise, share you code what you have done.

Comment: @debashish.ghosh The classical decorator pattern is applied to *classes* not functions. There are of course function decorators *in other languages* (and, yes, you can emulate them in C++). So, once again, please show us what you’ve tried. — That said, at a guess I’d say that what you’re looking for is [fixed-point combinators for functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Fixed-point_combinators_in_lambda_calculus), e.g. the Y combinator.

Comment: I guess you have [Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) in mind. However, we need more information in order to help you.

Comment: I have added the details of the code I started experimenting with. Requesting to reopen this. Let me know if any more details are needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can't decorate a recursive function in C++. The recursive calls are statically bound to the original function.

You *can* decorate a callable that calls what it expects to be named.

```
using fib_type = std::function<uint64_t(uint64_t)>;

fib_type fib = [](uint64_t n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
        return n;
    return fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1);
};

fib = memoized(fib);
```

Comment: You're right. Functions are not the right entity. After tweaking the decorator to take std::function, it worked. Thanks.